# Получить атрибут data через jquery

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер. Есть такой код (упрощенный)

```
<div data-user-email="<?=$users['email']?>" data-event-id="<?=$event['id']?>" class="event-div">

            <span class="my_btn delete-event" style="background-color: red;">Удалить</span>

            </div>
```

Этот блок выводить циклом, поэтому значения `data-user-email` и `data-event-id` разные. Как получить значение data атрибутов при нажатии на кнопку `delete-event` в текущем блоке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.delete-event').click(function(e){
    var parent = $(this).parent('.event-div');
    $("#result").html("Email: "+parent.data('user-email')+"; Event: "+parent.data('event-id'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bookin/dehgyo39/

Answer (score 0):

Через [нативный метод](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) объекта Node в ванильном JS.

```
$(".delete-event").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).dataset.eventId;
    var email = $(this).dataset.userEmail;
});
```

Comment: Вы забыли, что надо датасет взять не у объекта, на который нажали, а у предка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Судя по всему не заметил этого в вопросе. Прошу прощения у автора.

Answer (score 0):

[closest](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) - для каждого из выбранных элементов, closest() будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель, и так далее, до начало дерева DOM

```js
$('.delete-event').on('click', function() {
  var innerBlock = $(this).closest('.event-div');
  
  console.log('email: ' + $(innerBlock).data().userEmail + ', eventId: ' + $(innerBlock).data().eventId);
  
  /* для dataset
  var innerBlock = $(this).closest('.event-div')[0];  // var innerBlock = this.closest('.event-div'); 
  console.log('email: ' + innerBlock.dataset.userEmail + ', eventId: ' + innerBlock.dataset.eventId);
  */   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-user-email="userEmail666@mail.ru" data-event-id="eventId666" class="event-div">
  <span class="my_btn delete-event" style="background-color: red;">Удалить 666</span>
</div>

<div data-user-email="userEmail333@mail.ru" data-event-id="eventId333" class="event-div">
  <span class="my_btn delete-event" style="background-color: red;">Удалить 333</span>
</div>

<div data-user-email="userEmail999@mail.ru" data-event-id="eventId999" class="event-div">
  <span class="my_btn delete-event" style="background-color: red;">Удалить 999</span>
</div>
```